# PHP GD ttftext center alignment

Tags: php, image, text, graph, gd

I'm using [`imagettftext`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php) to make a **bar graph** and at the **top of each bar** I want to put the **value**.

I have the **following variables for each bar** (which are really rectangles)

`$x1`
`$y1`
`$x2`
`$y2`
`$imagesx`
`$imagesy`
`$font_size`

Also, The **fontsize should decrease as the string length increases.**

[image]

Comment: Boy, you're in for some work! Does it *have* to be PHP? There are such nice (and ready-made) javascript plotting libraries out there...

Comment: I'm making a PHP library so...

Comment: Would be nice to have "making bar graph" code for sample, can you post  it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do it like this. Remember to place the font file "arial.ttf" in current directory:

```
<?php
// Create a 650x150 image and create two colors
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(650, 150);
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);

// Set the background to be white
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 649, 149, $white);

// Path to our font file
$font = './arial.ttf';

//test it out
for($i=2;$i<10;$i++)
    WriteTextForMe($im, $font, str_repeat($i, $i), -140 + ($i*80), 70 + rand(-30, 30), -160 + (($i+1)*80), 150, $black);

//this function does the magic
function WriteTextForMe($im, $font, $text, $x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, $allocatedcolor)
{
    //draw bars
    imagesetthickness($im, 2);
    imagerectangle($im, $x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, imagecolorallocate($im, 100,100,100));

    //draw text with dynamic stretching
    $maxwidth = $x2 - $x1;
    for($size = 1; true; $size+=1)
    {
        $bbox = imagettfbbox($size, 0, $font, $text);
        $width = $bbox[2] - $bbox[0];
        if($width - $maxwidth > 0)
        {
            $drawsize = $size - 1;
            $drawX = $x1 + $lastdifference / 2;
            break;
        }
        $lastdifference = $maxwidth - $width;
    }
    $size--;
    imagettftext($im, $drawsize, 0, $drawX, $y1 - 2, $allocatedcolor, $font, $text);
}

// Output to browser
header('Content-type: image/png');

imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

It uses `imagettfbbox` function to get width of the text, then loops over the font size to get correct size, centers it and displays it.

**So, it outputs the following:**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate the center of your text by using PHP's [`imagettfbbox`-function](http://php.net/imagettfbbox):

```
// define text and font
$text = 'some bar label';
$font = 'path/to/some/font.ttf';

// calculate text size (this needs to be adjusted to suit your needs)
$size = 10 / (strlen($text) * 0.1);

// calculate bar center
$barCenter = $x1 + ($x2 - $x1) / 2;

// calculate text position (centered)
$bbox = imagettfbbox($size, 0, $font, $text);
$textWidth = $bbox[2] - $bbox[0];
$positionX = $textWidth / 2 + $barCenter;
$positionY = $y1 - $size;
```

**EDIT:** Updated the code to do all the work for you.

Comment: How *exactly* would you use it to get the place to write it so it becomes centered

Comment: I edited my post accordingly. The code calculates the x-axis position of the given text with center alignment `$positionX`.

Comment: Hmm let me re-write the question

Comment: Well, this is an incomplete answer, but you can't expect people to do all of your work for you. `imagettfbbox` is a tool you are definitely going to need for this, as it will give you the projected dimensions of the text. You can use that to center the text relative to each bar.

Comment: `$positionX = $textWidth / 2 + $barCenter; ` should be `$positionX = $barCenter - $textWidth / 2 ;`