# How do I align things?

Tags: php, gd

I'm looking to figure out how to align text (such as centered horizontally, and also reducing font size automatically if it's too long).

From playing around, x=0, y=0 isn't always the absolute top left (?), no idea what's causing this. It's kind of annoying to have to just keep changing numbers by one and refreshing.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out a starting point..

Comment: Here is your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679014/php-gd-ttftext-center-alignment

Answer (score 0):

Some functions define x, y as the **basepoint** of the first character, not as the top-lòeft corner of the generated string.

In other words, it is related to the strings's baseline: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baseline_(typography)

To properly align a TTF font (do you use TTF fonts?) you have to do some math with http://www.php.net/imagettfbbox

This function gives you the extent of the generated string.

Comment: Note the OP says: `Mostly looking to figure out how to: align text (such as centered horizontally, and also reducing font size automatically if it's too long.`